# php sine, cosine working strange

Tags: php, math

I was experimenting with the `sin` and `cos` functions in PHP, and I noticed that this code:

```
echo rad2deg(sin(deg2rad(pi())));
```

returned pi. However, this code:

```
echo asin(sin(pi()));
```

which you would think would give somewhere near pi (taking the inverse sine of the sine) actually returns this:

```
1.2246467991474E-16
```

I read through the PHP manual on sines and such, but I still can't figure out why this is working like this and how it works.

Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Confirmed that the arcsin of the sin of pi is zero: https://www.google.com/#q=arcsin(sin(pi)). The small value you produece is likely due to floating point error.

Comment: You should not use `deg2rad` on `pi()` (unless you want to convert 3.141... degrees to radian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function will actually calculate

```
180/pi*sin(pi*pi/180)
```

which is "close" to pi (for two digits), because `pi*pi/180` is relatively small, and for small values sin(x) is approximately x.

For your second code piece, one should know that `pi()` can't return an exact number of pi, but only one accurate to 53 binary digit.
In fact, if you calculate (with higher precision) `eps=frac(pi*2^52)/2^52` you get about 1.2246467991474E-16., so `sin(pi())=sin(pi-eps)=-sin(-eps)=sin(eps) ~= eps`. And of course, `asin` can't guess which was the original value passed to `sin`, so it will always return a value between -pi/2 and +pi/2.

Answer (score 0):

The sinus of 0 degrees, 180 degrees (pi radians), 360 degrees (2*pi radians), etc. are all `0`.

So taking the arcsin of that result (0) will get you `0` back.

**Edit:** It *is* about the math: From 0 to 360 degrees (0 - 2*pi radians), the sinus will fluctuate between -1 and 1. And the arcsin value of any valid number you can take the arcsin of (between -1 and 1...) will always return a number between -0.5*pi and 0.5*pi. So it can never be pi.

See a simple example [here](https://eval.in/706395).

Comment: This isn't so much about the math side of it, rather the PHP side. I know that the sine of any multiple of pi is 0. I'm asking why my PHP is not returning that.

Comment: If I have a number `x` and take the sine of it, what function should I then use to return that number, or a number close to that number? For example, if I give the function the sine of 4, it will give me back ~3.9.

Answer (score 0):

As `sin(x)=x+O(x^3)`, for small factors `e` and mediums sized arguments `x` you get that

```
1/e*sin(e*x) = x + O(e^2*x^3)
```

The conversion factor `pi/180` from degrees to radians can count as small enough so that the higher order terms do not influence the first digits too much. But in no case is the result from your first experiment exactly `pi`.